# Marshal dynamic JSON field tags in Go

Tags: json, go, terraform

I'm trying to generate JSON for a [Terraform file](http://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax.html). Because I (think I) want to use marshalling instead of rolling my own JSON, I'm using Terraforms JSON format instead of the 'native' TF format.

```
{
  "resource": [
    {
      "aws_instance": {
        "web1": {
          "some": "data"
        }
    }]
}
```

`resource` and `aws_instance` are static identifiers while `web1` in this case is the random name. Also it wouldn't be unthinkable to also have `web2` and `web3`.

```
type Resource struct {
    AwsResource AwsResource `json:"aws_instance,omitempty"`
}

type AwsResource struct {
    AwsWebInstance AwsWebInstance `json:"web1,omitempty"`
}
```

The problem however; **how do do I generate random/variable JSON keys with Go's field tags?**

I have a feeling the answer is "You don't". What other alternatives do I have then?

Comment: You could use a lexer based approach like [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs), but then you don't get the idiomatic struct goodness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases where there are names not known at compile time, a map can be used:

```
type Resource struct {
    AWSInstance map[string]AWSInstance `json:"aws_instance"`
}

type AWSInstance struct {
    AMI string `json:"ami"`
    Count int `json:"count"`
    SourceDestCheck bool `json:"source_dest_check"`
    // ... and so on
}
```

Here's an example showing how to construct the value for marshalling:

```
r := Resource{
    AWSInstance: map[string]AWSInstance{
        "web1": AWSInstance{
            AMI:   "qdx",
            Count: 2,
        },
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/qd869xPhMz)

Comment: But that's a solution for Unmarshalling, in which case a map and a for loop would be sufficient. But I need to dynamic naming on the output/marshalling.

Comment: Ahh, naming them when initialising the struct. Hadn't thought of that, thanks!